# Using threads and processes together with shared queues in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I'm trying to use a multithreading queue and a multiprocessing queue at the same time. The threading queue will be used by 20 threads to retrieve many web pages. I then want to put the pages into a multiprocess queue so that 4 process workers can crunch the data. Below is my basic structure. My issue is that, the work queue, gives an error saying Queue is not iterable. I think the multithreading queue is overwriting the multiprocess queue but I really don't know what's wrong.

```
ticker_queue = Queue()

work_queue = Queue()
tickers = get_tickers()


for i in tickers:
    ticker_queue.put(i)

for i in range(20):
    t = Thread(target=network_worker, args = (ticker_queue, work_queue)).start()

for i in range(4):
    p = Process(target = worker, args = (work_queue)).start()
```

Here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "OneDrive\Python\andys.py", line 108, in <module>
    p = Process(target = worker, args = (work_queue)).start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 104, in __init__
    self._args = tuple(args)
TypeError: 'Queue' object is not iterable
```

Comment: boil your problem down to a simple self-contained example, then post your example and the traceback. Nobody's seen professor Xavier for a while.. ;-)

Comment: I have to go to work in a few, I will post a self-contained example later tonight if no one has responded. Thanks.

Comment: You're missing a comma: `p = Process(target = worker, args = (work_queue,)).start()`

Comment: WOW! A COMMA! Thanks a bunch! It worked. Programming syntax sometimes... -.-

Comment: I've added it as an answer for future users..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a comma missing in

```
p = Process(target = worker, args = (work_queue)).start()
```

since

```
(work_queue)
```

is just an expression, while what you want is a 1-element tuple:

```
(work_queue,)
```

notice the additional comma.